# How to extract data specific data from many websites

Tags: jsoup

I have to extract the contact information  in a text format of many website. How can I extract? Let's see an example:

```
Document doc=Jsoup.connect("http://www.genesyslab.com/").get();
```

Here I am connecting to the site. I want to extract Products information of this site.

Comment: You have to understand what HTML elements are and how they are scruturec in the page you are trying to access. We could give you the product list for that site right now, but if you don't understand it, as soon as they change just a bit, the whole program will stop working. You should first go through a basic HTML tutorial.

Comment: Have you ever used `Jsoup` before? Please go through the examples here : http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/ . You will then be able to answer your own question.

Comment: Actually i am new in jsoup , now i am able to get the data from a single website ,but let's an example ,i have to parse all the about us data from any website then what i hav to write?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should put all the urls you need in a file, then load the file and extract information in a loop. For example:

```
//Load file with urls into array
for (url : array) {
  //connect to url
  //extract data
  //send data to file
}
```